# Is there a way to detect UIGestures on a subview covered by another subview?

Tags: ios, swift

I have two subviews in a view: 
1. Subview "Object" handles UIGestures such as TapGestures or PanGestures. 
2. Subview "Cover" is a blue view "above" the "Object" subview with 50% opacity (so you can still see the "Object" subview.

Right now the "Cover" subview is blocking any of the UIGestures on Object from being detected because it's above the "Object" subview / is higher in the hierarchy. Is there a way to keep "Cover" above "Object but still allow UIGestures to be detected and used by "Object?"

Comment: You have 2 views cover view above the Object view and both have the gestures applied. What you want to achieve?
Can you please more explore your question. Is your view is parallel or the above view is just hold 50% of the UI? why you need the tapping on such a view which is hiding behind some other view that visible due to opacity?

Comment: @AshwiniSalunkhe only the Object view has gestures applied, and the two views are parallel and so the cover view is covering the object view entirely. It is fine if it's not possible to have this functionality but I'm just trying to understand if it was possible.

Comment: Okay as per my understanding it is not possible because the user interaction of view is only be notified when you do some interaction on that view may be tapping, swiping.
But in this case the both view are parallel and when you tap/ swipe on view that time view is "Cover" view not the "Object" view. In the interaction "Object" view doesn't come into the picture. That's why "Object" doesn't recognise any interaction.
I hope you understand what I mean to say.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Comment: Object can already receive interactions - I'm just trying to understand if there's a way to handle touches if the Object view is covered entirely by another view.